# Create Three Columns from a Counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, pandas

Right now, my Counter looks like this:

```
(('you', 'call'), 3.2875047316896584): 1, 
(('bonus', 'offer'), 5.880001319229578): 1, 
(('without', 'warranty'), 10.11244740522995): 1
```

I am trying to pass these values into a Pandas DF with Three columns, Bigrams, Score, and Frequency

So for example, using the first value above, my expected DF looks like

```
 Bigrams        Score                   Frequency
 you call       3.2875047316896584         1
```

I am trying to use this bit of code to do so, but it keeps giving me an error

```
 c = Counter()
 frequencies = [[" ".join(k),v,d] for k,v,d in c]
 frame = pd.DataFrame(frequencies, columns=['Bigrams','Score','Frequency'])
```

However, this keeps saying: Value Error: need more than 2 values to unpack.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using both keys and values.  Iterating a dictionary (mapping) yields keys only. Use [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) to make it yields both.

And, use tuple unpacking correctly. It should match items yielded.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> c = Counter({
...     (('you', 'call'), 3.2875047316896584): 1,
...     (('bonus', 'offer'), 5.880001319229578): 1,
...     (('without', 'warranty'), 10.11244740522995): 1
... })
>>> frequencies = [[" ".join(k),v,d] for (k, v), d in c.items()]
>>> frame = pd.DataFrame(frequencies, columns=['Bigrams','Score','Frequency'])
>>> print(frame)
            Bigrams      Score  Frequency
0       bonus offer   5.880001          1
1  without warranty  10.112447          1
2          you call   3.287505          1
```